# Comapare values in same column same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-in

My table is

> Product(maker, model, type)

I want to select type and maker  of only the same type and also having count of models greater than one.

Sample data:

```
maker             model         type
-------------------------------------
 A                 123        computer
 B                 234         laptop
 B                 345         laptop
 C                 456         printer
 C                 543           PC
```

The answer for the above sample data is B and laptop because maker B manufactures only laptops and also more than one model.It is not maker A because even though he manufactures product of same type he has only one model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy. You are looking for makers with a record count > 1 and a count of distinct types = 1:

```
select maker
from product
group by maker
having count(distinct type) = 1 and count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: I want both maker and type if I include type it shows "Column 'Product.type' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause".If i add type in group by the result becomes wrong.

Comment: As you select those makers with only _one_ type, you can select min(type) or max(type) - which are of course the same - to show the type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT maker 
FROM Product
GROUP BY maker, type
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```